# LibGDX: How to simulate that the Android back button was pressed

Tags: android, libgdx

In my libGDX game I'm using `Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);` to catch the Android back button in order to switch screens or to show an exit confirmation dialog on my main menu screen. When the user confirms to exit, I call an exitGame method which calls `game.dispose()`.

When I call only `game.dipose()` (which should hide the current screen on default), nothing happens. When I additionally call `batch.dispose()` or `Assets.dispose()`, the game crashes with `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x77738008 (code=1), thread 25492 (Thread-21222)`.

How can I call the normal Android reaction that I would get without catching the back button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for.-

```
Gdx.app.exit();
```

You can find further information in [Libgdx Docs](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Application.html#exit--).

Comment: Oh, so easy. Thanks! I thought I had read somewhere that this was only valid for desktop applications.